# How to write in to a text file repeatedly when function is called in c language

Tags: c

I created a c program such that when a particular function is called it should create text file ,a path in c/ some foldername/log files. The time,date at which the function is called and terminated  is to be stored in to the text file. I have tried with the code below.

```
function() {
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    time_t current_time;
    char* c_time_string;

    /* Obtain current time as seconds elapsed since the Epoch. */
    current_time = time(NULL);

    if (current_time == ((time_t)-1))
    {
        (void) fprintf(stderr, "Failure to compute the current time.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Convert to local time format. */
    c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);

    if (c_time_string == NULL)
    {
        (void) fprintf(stderr, "Failure to convert the current time.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    fp=fopen("C:\\X2.6\\X_LogFiles\\file.txt","w"););

    /* Print to stdout. */

    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
    putc( c_time_string,fp);
    fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

I am a new beginner in c. i explored but i could not able to find function to write time and the data text file got erased when i am calling the function again

Thanks for reply in advance

Answer (score 0):

the data in your file is getting erased because you are opening the file in write mode (the "w" in your fopen() command )

```
    fp=fopen("C:\\X2.6\\X_LogFiles\\file.txt","w");
```

whenever you open a file in "w" mode. if the file is not present it will be created. But if the file is present **the file will be emptied, all its data is deleted and then opened**

If you want to append (add to the already existing file) to the file, you should use "a" inplace of "w". the append mode will create the file if it is not there. But if the file is there, then it is just opened to add (append) data to it

Answer (score 0):

use `printf` to write the time to the file.

`printf(file_descriptor, "control_String");`

here it would be

`printf(fp," %s\n", asctime (current_time) );`

also open the file in append mode `a`

```
fFILE *fp;
char ch;
time_t current_time;
char* c_time_string;

/* Obtain current time as seconds elapsed since the Epoch. */
time(&current_time);

if (current_time == ((time_t)-1))
{
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "Failure to compute the current time.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

/* Convert to local time format. */
c_time_string = ctime(&current_time);

if (c_time_string == NULL)
{
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "Failure to convert the current time.");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}


fp=fopen("C:\\X2.6\\X_LogFiles\\file.txt","a"););

/*changed here*/

fprintf(fp,"%s",c_time_string);


fclose(fp);
```

return 0;
}

Comment: I am facing the below errors at printf statement             Type error in argument 1 to `printf'; found 'pointer to FILE' expected 'pointer to const char'.
 Type error in argument 1 to `asctime'; found 'time_t' expected 'pointer to const struct tm'.

Comment: Sorry...it was `fprintf` not `printf` editing the original post

Comment: Type error in argument 1 to `asctime'; found 'time_t' expected 'pointer to const struct tm'.
Still i am facing the error in fprinf statement

Comment: please ignore that `asctime`. I was not sure what I was doing. Edited the reply. The edit works fine. checked. Thank you